# Swift Draw Custom Circle

Tags: swift, geometry, uibezierpath

I am trying to implement a custom circular analysis view.
The view should be circular but cut-off.

**Goal:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: innerRect.minX, y: innerRect.minY, width: innerRect.width, height: innerRect.height))

if trackBackgroundColor != UIColor.clear {
    trackBackgroundColor.setFill()
    circlePath.fill();
}
if trackBorderWidth > 0 {
    circlePath.lineWidth = trackBorderWidth
    trackBorderColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.stroke()
}    

// progress Drawing
let progressPath = UIBezierPath()
let progressRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: innerRect.minX, y: innerRect.minY, width: innerRect.width, height: innerRect.height)
let center = CGPoint(x: progressRect.midX, y: progressRect.midY)
let radius = progressRect.width / 2.0

let startAngle:CGFloat = clockwise ? CGFloat(-internalProgress * Double.pi / 180.0) : CGFloat(constants.twoSeventyDegrees * Double.pi / 180)
let endAngle:CGFloat = clockwise ? CGFloat(constants.twoSeventyDegrees * Double.pi / 180) : CGFloat(-internalProgress * Double.pi / 180.0)

progressPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius:radius, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise:!clockwise)
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

How do I draw the custom circle described as Goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a rough implementation of what you need. This draws the two arcs.

```
class CircularProgressView: UIView {
    var trackBackgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    var trackBorderWidth: CGFloat = 10
    var progressColor = UIColor.red
    var percent: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    // Adjust these to meet your needs. 90 degrees is the bottom of the circle
    static let startDegrees: CGFloat = 120
    static let endDegrees: CGFloat = 60

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let startAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: CircularProgressView.startDegrees)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: CircularProgressView.endDegrees)
        let progressAngle = radians(of: CircularProgressView.startDegrees + (360 - CircularProgressView.startDegrees + CircularProgressView.endDegrees) * CGFloat(max(0.0, min(percent, 1.0))))

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(center.x, center.y) - trackBorderWidth / 2 - 10

        print(startAngle, endAngle, progressAngle)
        let trackPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        let progressPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: progressAngle, clockwise: true)
        trackPath.lineWidth = trackBorderWidth
        trackPath.lineCapStyle = .round
        progressPath.lineWidth = trackBorderWidth
        progressPath.lineCapStyle = .round

        trackBackgroundColor.set()
        trackPath.stroke()

        progressColor.set()
        progressPath.stroke()
    }

    private func radians(of degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return degrees / 180 * .pi
    }
}

let progress = CircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 400))
progress.backgroundColor = .white
progress.percent = 0.95
```